# porque tá retornando boolean false?

Tags: php

Tenho uma consulta e ela retorna boolean false sempre quando uso `var_dump($row)`.

```
$tokenHash = $query->fetchColumn(10);


    if($query->rowCount() === 0 || (hash_equals($tokenHash, $tokenGet) === FALSE)):
        echo 'Token Inválido!';
        header( "refresh:10;url=listBillsReceive.php" );
        exit;
    else:
        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Porque?

Comment: em que ponto do código você esta colocando esse var_dump?

Comment: depois de $row = query-fetch(PDO::FETCH)...

Comment: Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código completo? Você pode adicionar ao objeto de conexão com o banco de dados o seguinte trecho: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`, sendo `$db` o objeto de conexão, para que em qualquer erro dado seja levantada uma exceção.